# Call another activity from button on camera Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera

I'm implementing a Camera app on Android, I'd like to have a button on it which will lead the user to the developer website, or my website.

This button is placed right of the shutter button.

I was trying to call the webview activity from this button, but it's giving me errors and I'm confused on this case, because there are plenty of examples of calling an activity inside another one, but no from a camera app.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Here's the piece of code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity /**implements OnClickListener**/ {

ImageView image;
Activity context;
Preview preview;
Camera camera;
Button exitButton;
ImageView fotoButton;
Button webButton;
LinearLayout progressLayout;
String path = "/sdcard/KutCamera/cache/images/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;

    webButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView_world);
    fotoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto);
    exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_photo);
    progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);

    preview = new Preview(this,
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.KutCameraFragment));
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    frame.addView(preview);
    preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    fotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                takeFocusedPicture();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            exitButton.setClickable(false);
            fotoButton.setClickable(false);
            webButton.setClickable(true);
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    webButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Everytime I run it it throws me this error:

```
4-04 00:33:43.929    4237-4237/com.kut.kutcamera E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kut.kutcamera/com.kut.kutcamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.kut.kutcamera.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The layout declaration of the world button is just Okay, I don't really think it's because of that, I guess there is something inside that camera method that doesn't allows me to properly make the call.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

activiy_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/KutCameraFragment"
    android:name="com.kut.camera.KutCameraFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewReferan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Photo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textColor="#2799CF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/islem_value_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..." />

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_foto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"
            android:contentDescription="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_photo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/fotocekicon"
            android:contentDescription="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_world"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/world"
            android:contentDescription="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mark3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your layout file of main activity?

Comment: The exception clear indicate that you are try to cast the image view with button

Comment: Hi Bhavdip, thanks, added the layout for mainactivity

Comment: Yes, but it is an image, the button has an image though

Comment: fotoButton for example is working, and has an image as design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have update your activity class, just replace with my code let me know you still face the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity /**implements OnClickListener**/ {

ImageView image;
Activity context;
Preview preview;
Camera camera;
Button exitButton;
ImageView fotoButton;
ImageView webButton;
LinearLayout progressLayout;
String path = "/sdcard/KutCamera/cache/images/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;

    webButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_world);
    fotoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto);
    exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_photo);
    progressLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);

    preview = new Preview(this,
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.KutCameraFragment));
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    frame.addView(preview);
    preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    fotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                takeFocusedPicture();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            exitButton.setClickable(false);
            fotoButton.setClickable(false);
            webButton.setClickable(true);
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    webButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: No, Thank YOU mate! lol, super awesome, gonna look for changes to understand better why the error, Thank you very much again!

Comment: You welcome. Try to identify the exceptions in log cat.

Comment: -1.  Please don't just post code without saying why is fixes the problem.  Nobody learns from that.  The OPs problem is a simple one and they go away no better than when they asked the question.  You should also only show the changed code.  What's the point of posting the entire activity?